# Magento 2 while reindex INSERT INTO 'catalog_category_product_index_store1' stuck the query

Tags: magento2, reindex

I am working on Magento 2.3.2. When I run re-index command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` **Design Config Grid** and **Customer Config Grid** is completed. But it is taking too much time to re-index **Category Products** and **Product Categories**

I checked the `SHOW PROCESSLIT;` in my database and i am getting following query which is running from while.

> INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product_index_store1

After a long time it is displaying

> INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product_index_store2

I **tried** to **reset** the **indexer** and again re-index only those two indexer. But same thing happening.

I have **60k Products** in my Magento Store.

It is suddenly happened from few days in live only. In local it is re-indexing everything. The issue is only in live. I have same number of products in local.

Is it any permission issue to any folder like var or generated ?

Please guide me on that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [set up cron in Magento 2](https://meetanshi.com/blog/set-cron-in-magento-2/)

When you set up **Magento 2**, it is compulsory to set up **cron**.

So, when the **cron** runs according to the schedule, the tasks are completed automatically.

And, it won't take more time in **indexing**.

Also i would advise you to use the good and Magento optimized server like **Nexcess** or **Fastcomet** Cloud Servers

Hope it helps.

Comment: Cron is already setup. It is re-indexing when the cron run. But sometimes the lots of query run like search_tmp_5e42d7f8549d57_70716887` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id` and above mentioned and the website get down.

Comment: So can you check with your server i would advise you to use good optimized server because 60K product is very much.